# Is there a list of the datalab keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I've started going through the initial tutorials and documentation for the datalab, and they do provide suggested keyboard shortcuts occasionally, but I couldn't seem to find a list of them anywhere so I could explore the various options.

Any links or guidance (or even a command I could type in within datalab that would list all the shortcuts), would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I was poking around more and I found that at least some of them are listed in the top-right of the datalab, by clicking on the '?', and then selecting 'Keyboard Shortcuts'.

Not sure how I missed this on my first searches through the ui, but now I know. :)

Comment: Several keyboard shortcuts are common between Jupyter and Datalab. You may also find it helpful to view the Jupyter keyboard shortcut help dialog that is accessible within a datalab notebook. To open the Jupyter keyboard shortcut help dialog, open a datalab notebook, then press esc to enter command mode, then press h.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the command palette to see shortcuts, and do commands that do not have a key assigned. On a mac it is Shift-Cmd-P.